# php-fpm and nginx : file not found

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a very common but annoying error, the classical : "File not found".
I have the following nginx.conf :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name aperophp;

    root /home/gline/mysite/web;

    location = / {
        try_files @site @site;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @site;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    location @site {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    } 
}
```

But I have this file :

```
$ ls -ld /home/gline/mysite/web/index.php 
-rw------- 1 gline gline 66 Jan  5 13:25 /home/gline/mysite/web/index.php
```

If you have some idea.

For your help,
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that php-fpm can read this php file, check if you have

```
 user = gline
 group = gline
```

in your php-fpm conf file regarding pool.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not readable by the PHP process.

You can see that the permissions on the script permit only the user `gline` to read (or write) to the file, but PHP by default runs under a different user ID (e.g. `nobody` or `www-data`).

To resolve the issue, make the file world readable. You may also need to make the containing directory and its parent directories searchable.

```
chmod a+r /home/gline/mysite/web/index.php
chmod a+x /home/gline/mysite/web
chmod a+x /home/gline/mysite
chmod a+x /home/gline
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot of odd things going on in this conf.

It's returning 404, because you're telling it to.  Anything ending in .php will match the `location ~ \.php$` block.

Also, why do you have the two `/` location blocks?

It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve from the conf file, but this is a pretty standard nginx/php conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name aperophp;

    root /home/gline/mysite/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have a 403 instead, even if index.php and its parent directory have a 0777 chmod. `2013/02/21 16:37:46 [error] 6402#0: *1 directory index of "/home/gline/mysite/web/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: aperophp, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "aperophp"`